# Prevent form submission leading to redirect while debugging

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I was not sure which tags to add here.

I'm adding some tracking to formSubmit events in Javascript. I would like to experiment by submitting the form several times in my browser and wondered if theres some setting in Chrome or some JS I can type in the console that would prevent the form redirecting when I submit it?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/InstanceOfMichael/f6a509b84fe82a718816

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have jQuery on your page, and your form has an ID, you could run this in your console before debugging:

```
$("#formId").submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

This can be done more verbosely without either condition as:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].onsubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
};
```

The second assumes the form in question is the first form on your page. The index may need to be adjusted.

For all forms with jQuery:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

Or without jQuery:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("form")).forEach(
  (form) => {
    form.onsubmit = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); };
  });
```

Note - the function is called through the Array prototype because `document.getElementsByTagName` returns an HTMLCollection rather than an Array.

For the two without jQuery, you may run into issues if you are trying to test a submit handler that you have already bound to your form. If that is the case, replace

```
form.onsubmit = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); };
```

with this:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

It is slightly longer, but won't overwrite any existing event handlers bound to the form.

Comment: Glad I could help :)